# Why replacing max pool by average pool using Keras APIs fails?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to replace max pooling layers in a pre-trained network with average pooling layers using Keras APIs. Somehow it doesn't work for me. I would highly appreciate if you could help me to figure out how to implement it.

Below is my current solution:

```
def replace_max_by_average_pooling(model):

    input_layer, *other_layers = model.layers
    assert isinstance(input_layer, keras.layers.InputLayer)

    x = input_layer.output
    for layer in other_layers:
        if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.MaxPooling2D):
            layer = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(
                pool_size=layer.pool_size,
                strides=layer.strides,
                padding=layer.padding,
                data_format=layer.data_format,
                name=f"{layer.name}_av",
            )
        x = layer(x)

    return keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer.input, outputs=x)
```

When I try to use this function on VGG net:

```
vgg = keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False, weights="imagenet")
vgg_av = replace_max_by_average_pooling(vgg)
```

If I print the summary it looks good:

> _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, None, None, 3)     0
>   _________________________________________________________________ block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792
>   _________________________________________________________________ block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928
>   _________________________________________________________________ **block1_pool_av (AveragePooli** (None, None, None, 64)    0
>   _________________________________________________________________ block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856
>   _________________________________________________________________ block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584
>   _________________________________________________________________ **block2_pool_av (AveragePooli** (None, None, None, 128)   0
>   _________________________________________________________________ block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168
>   ...

However, if I try to build a new model based on a few layers from `vgg_av`:

```
layer = vgg_av.get_layer("block3_conv1")
keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg_av.layers[0].input, outputs=layer.output).summary()
```

**somehow the average pooling layers are again replaced by max pooling layers:**

> _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, None, None, 3)     0
>   _________________________________________________________________ block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792
>   _________________________________________________________________ block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928
>   _________________________________________________________________ **block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)**   (None, None, None, 64)    0
>   _________________________________________________________________ block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856
>   _________________________________________________________________ block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584
>   _________________________________________________________________ **block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)**   (None, None, None, 128)   0
>   _________________________________________________________________ block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168
>   ================================================================= Total params: 555,328 Trainable params: 555,328 Non-trainable params:
>   0
>
> ---

Am I doing something wrong? Why and where?

My guess is that on this line `x = layer(x)` new operations are added to the computational graph such that the new operations have name `*name of an old operation*_1`, and when I call `vgg_av.get_layer("block3_conv1")` it still fetches a subgraph from `vgg`. But if I print the layer names in `vgg_av`, the names are the same as in `vgg`. And why it only fails when I try to get a subset of layers? I thought to completely rebuild the computational graph, but maybe there are some Keras APIs that I'm missing or I'm missing something conceptually.

Comment: It would be interesting to know "what fails"...

Comment: @DanielMöller ok I updated in the question to make it more clear. Basically if I build a new model based on a subset of layers from `vgg_av`, I get again max pooling layers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that whenever you reuse a layer (you're reusing layers when creating the new branch with avg poolings), you create a new node in the graph.

The original model still exists, and uses the nodes of index 0 for all layers, while your new model uses the nodes of index 1.

Layers should have the method `get_output_at(index)` or something similar to this, to which you pass the node you want to get the output from. I would guess from my past experience that simply `layer.output` would bring an error since you have more than one node (but surprisingly the code is accepting that - keras versions vary, I guess).

So, you should achieve your goal by using:

```
layer = vgg_av.get_layer("block3_conv1")
output = layer.get_output_at(1)
keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg_av.layers[0].input, outputs=output).summary()
```

It should be a good idea to count the number of `.outputs` of the last layer of your new models inside `replace_max_by_average_pooling` after calling the last layer, in case you're going to have more models like this from the same original model (meaning more nodes).

---

### Hack suggestion

Saving and loading models in Keras offers a system (initially meant for custom layers and custom functions) in which you define what keras should use for class names and function names it doesn't know.

Loading a model is "creating a model again with saved parameters". So, if you use this system to "replace" an existing name, it should work replacing layers during the model reconstruction.

```
custom_objects = {'MaxPooling2D': AveragePooling2D} 
vgg.save_model(filename)
vgg_ag = keras.models.load_model(filename, custom_objects = custom_objects)
```

If this doesn't work, you can make a custom function that returns an avg pooling using the given parameters like:

```
def createAvgFromMax(**params):

    #study the params, choose what to keep and discard
    return AveragePooling2D(....)
```

And `custom_objects = { 'MaxPooling2D': createAvgFromMax }`

Comment: Nice, it does work! I didn't know about `get_output_at`!  Have to read more about it. Thank you a lot for your help. Before I accept the answer, I would appreciate if you could give your input if it would it be possible/does make sense to replace nodes rather creating new ones?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to replace nodes. If it is, it should be very complicated and involves diving into source code to know how to.

Comment: Ok, good. I think you suggestion about keeping track of the count how many times I update the model can be a way to go. Thank you again!

Comment: But you could hack this model in a dirty way using `custom_objects = {'MaxPooling2D' : CustomClassThatCreatesAvgPoolingFromTheConfigParams}`, `original_model.save(filename)` and `new_model = keras.models.load_model(filename, custom_objects=custom_objects)`.

Comment: Looks really dirty :)

Comment: See the updated answer :) -- Sounds like it would work directly just replacing the classes (since they take very similar parameters)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion anyways! Also you could remove the warning that you didn't test the solution. I didn't test yet the hacks, otherwise it works.

Comment: Actually according to this page: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#the-concept-of-layer-node, I had to get `AttributeError`, when I try to access `output` with multiple nodes...

Comment: Excactly that I was expecting when I wrote " (but surprisingly the code is accepting that - keras versions vary, I guess)."

Comment: Yup.. I use `2.1.6-tf`, maybe I have to try it in the latest version.